# Hazelcast Mancenter enable/disable sanpshot

Tags: hazelcast

I am trying to configure wan replication using hazelcast mancenter, but I am not getting the option to select snapshot enable/disable feature here as the option is not listed in the dropdown.Is there a way to achieve this through mancenter?
Version 3.9.4
hazelcast version 3.9.3

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a WAN replication configuration dynamically to a cluster. It is for having one-off WAN sync operations, not continuous replication. The added configuration has two caveats:

- It is not persistent, so it will not survive a member restart.
- It cannot be used as a target for regular WAN replication. It can only be used for WAN sync.

That's why snapshot setting is not there as well. For adding a persistent WAN config, it must be defined in member configurations.